# C# - Change a multi-dimensional Array element Type

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional Array with unknown dimensions **at compile time** but at runtime (when i receive such Array) its dimension are described `int[] dimensions`. The length of `dimensions` is equal to the Rank of the Array and each element of `dimensions` contains the length of the relevant dimension.

What i want to obtain is a similar Array whose elements are mapped in a new object with a different type. I thought that LINQ could be useful so i wrote the following:

```
Array arr = ... //My multi-dimensional Array
var dimensions = ... //array describing the dimensions of arr. (NOT USED in the following but is an information i have)

var transformedArr = arr.Cast<StatusCode>().Select(val => JObject.FromObject(val)).ToArray();
```

It works but `transformedArr` is just a one-dimension Array now, hence i lost my multi-dimensional matrix. 
Have you got any idea to obtain a same Array with different element type only?

Please, note that **i don't know a priori the dimensions** of the array, only at runtime. In other words i can't use loops for indexing the multi-dimensional Array.

Any idea will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following function should meet your requirements

```
public static void RecursiveCopy<TInput, TOutput>(
    Array source,
    Array destination,
    int[] dimensions,
    Func<TInput, TOutput> mutate,
    int[] indexPrefix = null)
{
    indexPrefix = indexPrefix ?? new int[0];
    if (dimensions.Length != 1)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
        {
            var newDimensions = new int[dimensions.Length - 1];
            Array.Copy(dimensions, 1, newDimensions, 0, dimensions.Length - 1);

            var newIndexPrefix = new int[indexPrefix.Length + 1];
            Array.Copy(indexPrefix, 0, newIndexPrefix, 0, indexPrefix.Length);
            newIndexPrefix[indexPrefix.Length] = i;

            RecursiveCopy(source, destination, newDimensions, mutate, newIndexPrefix);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var currentIndex = new int[indexPrefix.Length + 1];
        Array.Copy(indexPrefix, 0, currentIndex, 0, indexPrefix.Length);
        for (var i = 0; i < dimensions[0]; i++)
        {
            currentIndex[indexPrefix.Length] = i;
            var value = source.GetValue(currentIndex);
            if (value is TInput)
            {
                var mutated = mutate((TInput)value);
                destination.SetValue(mutated, currentIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Different type. Expected " + nameof(TInput));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var transformedArr = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(StatusCode), dimensions);
RecursiveCopy<object, StatusCode>(arr, transformedArr, dimensions, i => i as StatusCode);
```

You can put real type instead of object

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you very much. Now i have to understand what you have written :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfs8044k(v=vs.110).aspx) to create your output array (using your `dimensions` as input), then using [GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/758awxk7(v=vs.110).aspx) to transform your values.

Comment: I can't use GetValue and SetValue because i don't know the dimensions of teh Array at compile time. So i don't know if it is a 2x3x5 or a 2x3x7x3, etc. In other words, i can't index the array in my code because i don't know how many dimension i have. I hope i was clear.

Comment: Did you look at these functions? They're specifically designed to enable your use case. You can use an array of indexes without compile time knowledge of the rank.

Comment: Of course i have looked them. The second parameter is "A one-dimensional array of 32-bit integers that represent the indexes specifying the position of the Array element to get." I can't pass an index because i don't know how indices are composed.